# Stop youtube video when popup is closed

Tags: jquery, wordpress, iframe, youtube

I am now a programmer and getting to know css.
I am student in Graphic Design building a website with Wordpress and the Divi theme for my grand project.
There is a plugin "Bloom" that will popup an embedded html youtube iframe, but when it is closed the video keeps playing. i have searched for a couple of days on the forums and could not quite understand how to make it stop.

Here is my html for the popup.

```
<html>
 <body>
 <iframe id="ytvideo2" width="640" height="360" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/IkktPPRahMU?rel=0&showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
 </body>
</html>
```

And the script that i found on the forums.

```
//First get theiframe URL
var url = $('#ytvideo').attr('src');

//Then assign the src to null, this then stops the video been playing
$('#ytvideo').attr('src', '');

// Finally you reasign the URL back to your iframe, so when you hide and load it again you still have the link
$('#ytvideo').attr('src', url);
```

I don't even know if this is the right script for me and where it supposed to go. :(
Hope anyone could help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well you will need to do that when the popup is closed. Check the plugin documentation to see if it offers any events for that.

Comment: add the script that you used to close the popup

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Youtube IFrame API.

Just ask if you need more help :D

https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference?hl=de